# Convert multiple year and month pay data in a monthly sum R

Tags: r

In R: I had two files that I have joined. Both contain commission pay data, I had two files because the pay structure periods of the jobs codes were different. For example, all the job codes in file one are paid commission monthly and all the job codes in file two are paid commission bi-monthly. 
  In order to accurately and fairly analyze the data I need to aggregate (sum) pay into a new field (let's call it "monthlypay") by month for each employee id (currently a factor), my problem is that I appear to successfully sum the pay for month for each employee, but currently it ignores the differing years. I'm not opposed to spreading year and month OR dummy coding from 6/2015-6/2017 as pay months 1-24, but I'm wondering if there is a way to do this all at once?

Current:

```
Check_DT   EMPLID   DEPTID JOBCODE PAY_FREQUENCY MAX._TTL.GROSS
2015-12-18 99999999 23231606  100880             W           1203
2015-12-24 99999999 23231606  100880             W            597
2015-12-31 99999999 23231606  100880             W            625
2016-01-08 99999999 23231606  100880             W            245
2016-01-13 99999999 23231606  100880             W            480
2016-01-15 99999999 23231606  100880             W            758
2016-01-22 99999999 23231606  100880             W            599
2016-01-29 99999999 23231606  100880             W            551
2016-02-05 99999999 23231606  100880             W            767
2016-02-12 99999999 23231606  100880             W            880
2016-02-19 99999999 23231606  100880             W            557
2016-02-26 99999999 20441606  100880             W            909
2016-03-04 99999999 20441606  100880             W            989
2016-03-11 99999999 20441606  100880             W            751
2016-03-18 99999999 20441606  100880             W            776
2016-03-25 99999999 20441606  100880             W            770
2016-04-01 99999999 20441606  100880             W            712
2016-04-08 99999999 20441606  100880             W            602
2016-04-15 99999999 20441606  100880             W            798
2016-04-22 99999999 20441606  100880             W            527
```

What I want (need actually, I am going to be running cluster analysis):

```
>Check_DT   EMPLID   DEPTID JOBCODE PAY_FREQUENCY MAX._TTL.GROSS Year Month Pay
>2015-12-18 99999999 23231606  100880             W           1203 2015 12 2425
>2015-12-24 99999999 23231606  100880             W            597 
>2015-12-31 99999999 23231606  100880             W            625
>2016-01-08 99999999 23231606  100880             W            245 2016 01 2633
>2016-01-13 99999999 23231606  100880             W            480
>2016-01-15 99999999 23231606  100880             W            758
>2016-01-22 99999999 23231606  100880             W            599
>2016-01-29 99999999 23231606  100880             W            551
>2016-02-05 99999999 23231606  100880             W            767
>2016-02-12 99999999 23231606  100880             W            880
>2016-02-19 99999999 23231606  100880             W            557
>2016-02-26 99999999 20441606  100880             W            909
>2016-03-04 99999999 20441606  100880             W            989
>2016-03-11 99999999 20441606  100880             W            751
>2016-03-18 99999999 20441606  100880             W            776
>2016-03-25 99999999 20441606  100880             W            770
>2016-04-01 99999999 20441606  100880             W            712
>2016-04-08 99999999 20441606  100880             W            602
>2016-04-15 99999999 20441606  100880             W            798
>2016-04-22 99999999 20441606  100880             W            527
```

etc...I am not even opposed to the year month and date for every year and month combo to repeated, I can get rid of duplicates. As a reminder some people in the file are paid weekly and others a paid bi-monthly.

Here is what I've done:

```
#Convert weekly/bimonthly pay to monthly sum of pay
  paydat_all$monthlypay <- month(paydat_all$Check_DT)
  aggregate(MAX._TTL.GROSS~monthlypay+EMPLID, FUN = sum, data = paydat_all)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should get you the results you're looking for

```
library(lubridate)
library(dplyr)

 data = 'Check_DT   EMPLID   DEPTID JOBCODE PAY_FREQUENCY MAX._TTL.GROSS
"2015-12-18" 99999999 23231606  100880             W           1203
"2015-12-24" 99999999 23231606  100880             W            597
"2015-12-31" 99999999 23231606  100880             W            625
"2016-01-08" 99999999 23231606  100880             W            245
"2016-01-13" 99999999 23231606  100880             W            480
"2016-01-15" 99999999 23231606  100880             W            758
"2016-01-22" 99999999 23231606  100880             W            599
"2016-01-29" 99999999 23231606  100880             W            551
"2016-02-05" 99999999 23231606  100880             W            767
"2016-02-12" 99999999 23231606  100880             W            880
"2016-02-19" 99999999 23231606  100880             W            557
"2016-02-26" 99999999 20441606  100880             W            909
"2016-03-04" 99999999 20441606  100880             W            989
"2016-03-11" 99999999 20441606  100880             W            751
"2016-03-18" 99999999 20441606  100880             W            776
"2016-03-25" 99999999 20441606  100880             W            770
"2016-04-01" 99999999 20441606  100880             W            712
"2016-04-08" 99999999 20441606  100880             W            602
"2016-04-15" 99999999 20441606  100880             W            798
"2016-04-22" 99999999 20441606  100880             W            527'

paydat_all <- read.table(text=data, header=TRUE, 
                         colClasses=c("Date", "character", "character", 
                                      "character", "factor", "integer"))

paydat_all <- paydat_all %>%
              mutate(Year = year(Check_DT),
                     Month = month(Check_DT)) %>%
              group_by(EMPLID, DEPTID, JOBCODE, Year, Month) %>%
              summarise(sum(MAX._TTL.GROSS))
```

Comment: I'm attempting to use the second version and getting the following error, can mutate only be used with an integer?: "Error in mutate_impl(.data, dots) : invalid subscript type 'integer"

Comment: Hey Matt, I appreciate you taking time to update your response, but I have an interesting phenomenon occurring, most of the time everything is accurate but for some employees the file will produce two rows for a certain year and month and split the pay into from two months in one and 3 in another. But, it doesn't do it for every 5 pay month....What do you think is occurring here?

Comment: NVM, it's becasue the Job Code was different

Comment: Anyway to generate the same flatten versioned even more into an average tenure pay for each EMPID? I'm trying the following but I suck at this. I'm more of a Data Analyst than a Data Scientist so I've been taking courses but haven't been able to apply my own successful code yet. I enjoy R for statistical purpose and want to learn the language over SAS. Here is what I have...avgpaydat_alltechs <- paydat_alltechs %>%
  mutate(AllPay = MonthlyPay) %>%
  group_by(CO, EMPLID, DEPTID, JOBCODE, PAY_FREQUENCY, Year, Month) %>%
  summarise(mean(MonthlyPay))

Comment: I just used aggregate to create a new field

Answer (score 1):

Consider base R's `ave` for inline aggregation where:

- first arg is a column to be aggregated
- one or more comma-separated args afterwards are factor levels to group by
- with explicit named `FUN` argument for aggregate type.

R script

```
data = 'Check_DT   EMPLID   DEPTID JOBCODE PAY_FREQUENCY MAX._TTL.GROSS
"2015-12-18" 99999999 23231606  100880             W           1203
"2015-12-24" 99999999 23231606  100880             W            597
"2015-12-31" 99999999 23231606  100880             W            625
"2016-01-08" 99999999 23231606  100880             W            245
"2016-01-13" 99999999 23231606  100880             W            480
"2016-01-15" 99999999 23231606  100880             W            758
"2016-01-22" 99999999 23231606  100880             W            599
"2016-01-29" 99999999 23231606  100880             W            551
"2016-02-05" 99999999 23231606  100880             W            767
"2016-02-12" 99999999 23231606  100880             W            880
"2016-02-19" 99999999 23231606  100880             W            557
"2016-02-26" 99999999 20441606  100880             W            909
"2016-03-04" 99999999 20441606  100880             W            989
"2016-03-11" 99999999 20441606  100880             W            751
"2016-03-18" 99999999 20441606  100880             W            776
"2016-03-25" 99999999 20441606  100880             W            770
"2016-04-01" 99999999 20441606  100880             W            712
"2016-04-08" 99999999 20441606  100880             W            602
"2016-04-15" 99999999 20441606  100880             W            798
"2016-04-22" 99999999 20441606  100880             W            527'

paydat_all <- read.table(text=data, header=TRUE, 
                         colClasses=c("Date", "character", "character", 
                                      "character", "factor", "integer"))
# MONTH AND YEAR
paydat_all[c("Month", "Year")] <- sapply(c("%m", "%y"), 
                                         function(d) format(paydat_all$Check_DT, d))

# THREE GROUP BY VARS WITH FORMAT() TO EXTRACT DATE TYPES
paydat_all$PaySum <- ave(paydat_all$`MAX._TTL.GROSS`, paydat_all$Month, 
                         paydat_all$Year, paydat_all$EMPLID, FUN=sum)
head(paydat_all)
#     Check_DT   EMPLID   DEPTID JOBCODE PAY_FREQUENCY MAX._TTL.GROSS Month Year PaySum
# 1 2015-12-18 99999999 23231606  100880             W           1203   12    15   2425
# 2 2015-12-24 99999999 23231606  100880             W            597   12    15   2425
# 3 2015-12-31 99999999 23231606  100880             W            625   12    15   2425
# 4 2016-01-08 99999999 23231606  100880             W            245   01    16   2633
# 5 2016-01-13 99999999 23231606  100880             W            480   01    16   2633
# 6 2016-01-15 99999999 23231606  100880             W            758   01    16   2633
```

Comment: Great that transformed it to look almost exactly how I wanted, just had to flip the "%m", "%y" ;)

Comment: Whoops! Definitely a typo. Edited accordingly. I hope solution helped.